# How secure is an encrypted text?

Tags: encryption, decryption

There are apps like [CTI Text Encryption](https://ctiencrypt.codeplex.com/) that encrypt texts with one or multiple passwords and render them into meaningless words and digits.

> e.x
>
> Original Text (before encryption):
>
> The quick brown fox jump over the lazy dog.
>
> Encrypted Text (after encryption):
>   ga8Ba3jH55sI4eFT0nRBesHoLGLbriXeWomE7vpxbFszJFnSXJRYy1MJoKy+y+krLmdmYxGBhRg3oRDA9OjqemJSZdryFI2b5BjseUnhsC8=
>
> Decryption Result of the Encrypted Text:
>
> The quick brown fox jump over the lazy dog.

So I have few questions

1. How secure are these encrypted texts?
2. Are they reversible and can one find the original text by using techniques used for hashes, encrypted files, truecrypt etc?
3. If possible then how long approx does it take to find the original text encrypted with 4 passwords and what hardware possibly needed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A peek at the source code, especially the [`AES256BitExpress.cs`](https://ctiencrypt.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#AES256BitExpress.cs) file, reveals the following excerpt:

```
    public static byte[] AES_Encrypt(byte[] bytesToBeEncrypted, byte[] passwordBytes)
    {
        byte[] encryptedBytes = null;
        byte[] saltBytes = passwordBytes;

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                AES.KeySize = 256;
                AES.BlockSize = 128;

                var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes, 1000);
                AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
                AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);
```

It uses AES (with a 256-bit key), which is good. It derives the key and IV from the password using [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) (that's what `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` implements), which is kinda OK (though 1000 iterations are a bit too low for comfort with modern machines). It uses the password itself as salt for PBKDF2, which can be described only as "atrociously weak". This totally ignores the point of the salt and allows parallel attacks, including time-wise parallelism (also known as "precomputed tables").

This is a nice illustration of how sane, secure algorithms can be assembled into something which offers only very little security. I can only advise against using that software for any security-related purpose.

Comment: It also makes the common "defender needs 3 blocks of output from PBKDF2 attacker only 2" mistake. But that's a minor quibble compared to the salting issue.